# Are there long-term lockers near Istanbul's Sabiha Gökçen airport?

Tags: luggage-storage, saw

I'm flying via Sabiha Gökçen airport and would like to leave some luggage there for a week.

Are there any long-term lockers inside the airport or somewhere nearby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just called the airport santral and they said there *is* a service as "baggage deposit" with locked cabinets (with insurance of course).

http://www.sabihagokcen.aero/passengers-and-visitors/before-flight/baggage-deposit

They said the price are (daily);

- Backpacks are 15 TL (Turkish lira)
- Middle size suitcases are 20 TL
- Large size suitcases are 25 TL

I don't know if there is a weight limit for them. The guy told me the price difference is just based on the luggage size. You can call them for more information with +90 216 588 88 02 number.